# Determinate mime type from MySQL column

Tags: php, mysql, blob, mime-types

I received an exported database from MSAccess (not my favorite) and I imported it to a MySQL table. There's a column named 'customerImage' and is a 'long BLOB' type with 'binary' as attribute. How can I determinate the Mime Type? I've tried different methods but all of them requires to be a file but data.

If someone could help me with PHP code or MySQL command would be great.

Comment: I'm not sure, but try doing `mime_content_type($mysql_row['blob_field')` (deprecated, I know, but most hosts haven't moved to PHP 5.3 yet). Also, not that you can change this (?), it's much better to store images out of the database.

Comment: I know, that database was made by other person. All columns can be entered/typed again but image column. PHP version is 5.2 ):

Answer (score 4):

IF your host still uses php 5.2 and dont have access to the fileinfo functions you can test the files header signature (magic numbers) to determine mime type

```
function mimetype($data)
{
    //File signatures with their associated mime type
    $Types = array(
    "474946383761"=>"image/gif",                        //GIF87a type gif
    "474946383961"=>"image/gif",                        //GIF89a type gif
    "89504E470D0A1A0A"=>"image/png",
    "FFD8FFE0"=>"image/jpeg",                           //JFIF jpeg
    "FFD8FFE1"=>"image/jpeg",                           //EXIF jpeg
    "FFD8FFE8"=>"image/jpeg",                           //SPIFF jpeg
    "25504446"=>"application/pdf",
    "377ABCAF271C"=>"application/zip",                  //7-Zip zip file
    "504B0304"=>"application/zip",                      //PK Zip file ( could also match other file types like docx, jar, etc )
    );

    $Signature = substr($data,0,60); //get first 60 bytes shouldnt need more then that to determine signature
    $Signature = array_shift(unpack("H*",$Signature)); //String representation of the hex values

    foreach($Types as $MagicNumber => $Mime)
    {
        if( stripos($Signature,$MagicNumber) === 0 )
            return $Mime;  
    }

    //Return octet-stream (binary content type) if no signature is found
    return "application/octet-stream"; 
}
```

**NOTE:** Some signatures may match partials of others, for instance the PK Zip file signature matches the first 4 bytes of java archive (.jar) file signature, **extra statements would be needed in the foreach loop to determine the correct signature for the mime type**, but for your situation this should do.

A updated list of file signatures can be found at http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html if someone needs more file signature types.

Comment: Most files worked for me, pdf's are not working. For some reason the stripos function doesn't find the Magic Number anywhere in the Signature although I can see it there. Any ideas?

Comment: @Patrick Evans I lost the database, I'm looking into my backup disks to found it and checked what you answered. I don't want to let this question as unanswered.

Answer (score 3):

The [**FileInfo**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) extension, and, more specifically, its [**`finfo_buffer()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-buffer.php) function, might help, here *(quoting)* :

> This function is used to get
>   information about binary data in a
>   string.

Fetching your binary data from database, and passing it to this function, might do the trick.

*Note : its comes with PHP >= 5.3*

Comment: Sad but true: I requested to the host company (hostgator) for update from PHP 5.2 to 5.3, they say the update date is undetermined.

Comment: oh :-( so typical :-( ; the other solution is http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php ; but it only works on files :-(

Answer (score 1):

Save the blob to a temp file and use the php [finfo_file](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.finfo-file.php) function on it.

Answer (score 0):

The [FileInfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) extension can be used. It contains a function called [`finfo_buffer()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-buffer.php)

Comment: Is there a solution or guide for PHP 5.2.11 / MySQL 5.0.92 ?