# Attempting to convert SQL Blob to image (From IOS DB, via PHP)

Tags: php, ios, sql, sqlite, blob

I have got a database from my iPhone which contains a massive amount of data.

The Columns are named:

- ID
- Thumbnail
- Data

The app it is from is mainly to do with pictures so this leads me to think that the app is storing the pictures into this table.

At closer look, the `Thumbnail` and `Data` are Blobs.

I am attempting to convert these Blobs back into a image (but I do not know what content-type they were before).

I have attempted to use `base64`, `file_put_contents`, `ibase_blob_echo` and most of the other ways you can convert a Blob in PHP.

The Blob's signature is: `BE 9A BC A4 37 25 78 72 7D (¾š¼¤7%xr})`

I was hoping to find the signature [Here](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) but unfortunately I was unable to find it.

I am not a IOS developer so I don't actually know how or the most common way of converting a image into a blob and retrieving it again; I just assumed that it would be the same as any other application.

If anyone can help me identify this Blob's type or could help me convert convert this Blob in PHP, I would much appreciate it.

(Please note that I do not wish to put the raw Blob data here)

Jamie

Answer (score 0):

You can create a db table to store and retrieve images in BLOB format. The important thing to remember is to set the correct header to the image type when displaying it. Here is how you do it, this is basic but you can make the code extensive and elaborate.

Please see [PHPRO Tutorial](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Storing-Images-in-MySQL-with-PHP.html).

too much code to put it on here. But this is the way you should do it or to have a good starting point.

if you don't know the type of the blob you can use

`imagecreatefromstring()` 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

it may auto-detect the blob.

or you can use this to find out if you don't know the MIME type of the BLOB:

```
function mimetype($data)
{
    //File signatures with their associated mime type
    $Types = array(
    "474946383761"=>"image/gif",                        //GIF87a type gif
    "474946383961"=>"image/gif",                        //GIF89a type gif
    "89504E470D0A1A0A"=>"image/png",
    "FFD8FFE0"=>"image/jpeg",                           //JFIF jpeg
    "FFD8FFE1"=>"image/jpeg",                           //EXIF jpeg
    "FFD8FFE8"=>"image/jpeg",                           //SPIFF jpeg
    "25504446"=>"application/pdf",
    "377ABCAF271C"=>"application/zip",                  //7-Zip zip file
    "504B0304"=>"application/zip",                      //PK Zip file ( could also match other file types like docx, jar, etc )
    );

    $Signature = substr($data,0,60); //get first 60 bytes shouldnt need more then that to determine signature
    $Signature = array_shift(unpack("H*",$Signature)); //String representation of the hex values

    foreach($Types as $MagicNumber => $Mime)
    {
        if( stripos($Signature,$MagicNumber) === 0 )
            return $Mime;  
    }

    //Return octet-stream (binary content type) if no signature is found
    return "application/octet-stream"; 
}
```

@ref: [Determinate mime type from MySQL column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304503/determinate-mime-type-from-mysql-column)

you can also expand the Types, MagicNumbers from this reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have attempted to use the way explained in that tutorial to display a blob but I do not know the content type of the Blob. I have gone through each individual MIME to see if it would work but each one would display a broken image. I am 100% sure that this blob is an image but I just cant seem to get it to display.

Comment: Thanks for another reply. I have attempted to use the above function (and also the finfo_file function) to try and determine the file type. Unfortunately, every function seems to reply with 'application/octet-stream'.The function above also gave me the following signature: be9abca4372578727d7233384042434537343234cbd53361043a2a2237357f79341e3339414a4346362732373434333841434344b05c323034343338 - This just left me more clueless about what the file type actually is.The database is approximately 800mb full of blobs and I have no idea what any of them contain (all of which was in my phone)

Comment: none of the data signatures match the MIME types? have you tried http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-buffer.php?

Comment: Indeed. The finfo_buffer also gives me "application/octet-stream; charset=binary". I just noticed that the first 563 letters are the same on each blob (ends with a ,); that got me thinking that there might be something else encoded with the blob itself. I tried removing the duplicate parts but I still get the same results when repeating everything I have done before. I honestly have tried everything I can think of, unless I try and see how the app decodes the images but unfortunately that is not possible. Do you have anything else in mind which could help my situation?